# How do translated, escaped strings (esc_attr) in Themes work?

Tags: translation, escaping

I was looking at the `TwentyEleven` code and found this:

```
esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyeleven' )
```

This is some code that came out of the title tag for a post; the full code within the title tag being:

```
printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyeleven' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) );
```

I checked out the documentation for the `esc_attr` function (appears to be the same as the `esc_attr__` function?) and it states it only takes one parameter, so how is this passing it two parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### General difference between `esc_attr` and `esc_attr_*`

The difference between [`esc_attr()`](http://queryposts.com/function/esc_attr/) and [`esc_attr__()`](http://queryposts.com/function/esc_attr__/), [`esc_attr_e()`](http://queryposts.com/function/esc_attr_e/), [`esc_attr_x()`](http://queryposts.com/function/esc_attr_x/) is that the later three are just "wrappers" or in other words higher level API functions.

When you look at the source of the later three, then you'll see that those put in a single argument wrapped in a call to [`translate()`](http://queryposts.com/function/translate/) (or [`translate_with_gettext_context()`](http://queryposts.com/function/translate_with_gettext_context/) for `esc_attr_x()`.

That means that you're just throwing two arguments in: The string to translate and the textdomain that helps WP determining which language file to take for the translation.

Everything else you see is the [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.sprintf.php) around it, which is default php function that replaces `%s`-parts and `%d`-parts in a string (string/digit).

### Minetrap! Be aware!

If you're *not passing* a second argument to the later three versions of `esc_attr()`, then you'll run into the following problem: WP now thinks that your strings are part of core and tries to translate them. Which can lead to very odd results.

Another thing that might happen is that the translation string (the 2nd arg) is already used by a plugin or theme. In this case, the later loaded translation file wins the race and is taken instead of your file. Again: Very odd results. Fix: Prefix your textdomain, as you'd do it with custom globals or function names.

### Conclusion

If you want to avoid a second argument, then simply go with `esc_attr( 'your string' )` and avoid the other three versions.

Comment: Sorry, what is a `textdomain`? I'm new to theming WP and have noticed several instances of WP passing in the 'twentyeleven' argument. Does this have to do with the theme name or something else?

Comment: The text-domain is the domain you're using for internationalization. More info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress and http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers